# What Is The Easiest Way to Measure a Short Distance With Laser Light?

Tags: optics, laser, interferometry

I'm an EE, so please forgive if this question is dumb.

The word "easiest" means, "What requires the least amount of optics experience?"

"Short distances" means 0.01 to 1 m.

I need to measure the distance between some datum and a moving object. Therefore, I don't necessarily need to measure absolute distance. It is sufficient to measure the change in distance.

One idea I had is to use a simple interferometer: Send laser light through a beamsplitter. The transmitted beam bounces off a target. Both transmitted and reflected beams reach a photodiode, which measures the interference between them. Each time the target moves lambda/4, there will be a peak in the interference pattern, and when the target moves lambda/4 again, there will be a valley. In this way I can count the pulses and know the change in position in increments of lambda. I don't actually need such fine resolution. +/- 0.1 mm is sufficient.

I think this will probably work, but it requires an optical bench, expensive parts, etc. What I'm more worried about is that I drop $4k on parts and then learn that I assumed something really dumb. That's what I mean when I say this approach requires expertise.

Time of flight does not seem practical owing to the very short distances. (If somebody out there knows how to clock an FPGA at 10 GHz I know a place that's hiring!!!)

Also, the sample rate needs to be at least 50 kHz.

Here are my questions:

1. Is there a method that is less expensive, requires less expertise, or both?
2. Is there a commercial, off the shelf product that will give me the same result? (0.01 - 1 m, 50 kHz, +/- 0.1 mm)

Comment: There is nothing dumb about the idea of using an interferometer. Not sure you are necessarily better off building one rather than buying one, though. There are plenty of commercial interferometric position measurement systems. For the kind of low precision that you are looking for, I would probably use a more robust inductive or capacitive digital linear position sensor.

Comment: A good resource to start with is the RP Photonics Encyclopedia and Buyer's Guide. For example, see the article on [Optical Metrology](https://www.rp-photonics.com/optical_metrology.html). Optical companies are used to helping their customers understand what is needed to solve their problems.

Comment: For your FPGA application, perhaps you should speak to Maxwell's Demon. He opens and closes a tiny door at a very high rate. He might have recommendations.

Comment: How large is the object? How fast does it move? How precise do you need to measure? How often? Way too many options based on the info supplied.